# Unable to click on Link text using Selenium IE web driver

Tags: c#

My code below doesn't work:

Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@class='ms-crm-Menu-Label']/span[@command='lead|NoRelationship|Form|Mscrm.Form.lead.ConvertQuick']"))).Click().Build().Perform();

```
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@class='ms-crm-CommandBar-Button ms-crm-Menu-Label-Hovered']")).Click();

        //driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@class='ms-crm-CommandBar-Menu']/li[@id='lead|NoRelationship|Form|Mscrm.Form.lead.ConvertLeadQuick']/span[@class='ms-crm-CommandBar-Button ms-crm-Menu-Label-Hovered']")).Click();
```

HTML:
    
        
        
        
     Qualify  Create a new engagement   
     Disqualify

***Note that all other buttons can be clicked, except the "Qualify" one.  Please anyone help.  Appreciated!

Comment: All above <li> ...</li> are wraped up by  <ul class="ms-crm-CommandBar-Menu">   .....<li> ...</li>....</ul>

Comment: Detail of "Qualify" as followings:                                                                                                 <li  class="ms-crm-CommandBarItem ms-crm-CommandBar-Menu ms-crm-CommandBar-Button" title="Qualify" id="lead|NoRelationship|Form|Mscrm.Form.lead.ConvertLeadQuick" command="lead|NoRelationship|Form|Mscrm.Form.lead.ConvertQuick" class="ms-crm-ImageStrip-ConvertLead_16 ms-crm-commandbar-image16by16" command="lead|NoRelationship|Form|Mscrm.Form.lead.ConvertQuick"> Qualify </span><div class="ms-crm-div-NotVisible">  </div>  </a> </span> </li>

Comment: Meta-comment: Rather than adding your clarifications as comments, you should edit them into your original post (using the edit option available below your question text).